# back date in shell script on solaris 5.10

Tags: shell, solaris-10

I am using **bash shell on Solaris 5.10**.Daily I get some files having name pattern **yyyy_mm_dd(like 2012_12_21)**.I keep only 3 days files and I delete the rest of them.Now I require 3 days back date to delete it.please suggest me how to get a backdate in shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard solution is to use `find`. If you really prefer to reinvent that particular wheel, `date -d "3 days ago"` will print the requested date.

```
find . -name '...' -mtime +3 -exec rm \+
```

Comment: it works till **find . -name '...' -mtime +3**,I will take care of the rest,thanks. **date -d "3 days ago "** does not work on my server (says illegal option)